# rails, unset value of checkboxes when none are selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dynamically generate a set of checkboxes in my view:

```
<% Event::NOTIFICATIONS.each do |notification| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "event[notifications][]", 
  notification, 
  @event.notifications.try(:include?, notification) %>
  <%= t("events.notifications.#{notification}") %>
<% end %>
```

The values are stored as an array.

However, when I edit an event and uncheck one of the notification boxes (so no notification boxes are left checked), it will not clear the array. The parameter hash does not contain the `notification` key either.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check_box_tag` doesn't work like `check_box`.  `check_box` creates a hidden field which returns `0` as the default value for an unchecked checkbox.  `check_box_tag`, on the other hand, doesn't return anything with the form if it is uncheked.  An easy way to solve this is to add a hidden field with the same name as the checkbox but with a value of `nil`.  This returns an array with a `nil` value as the first element which Rails should ignore.

```
hidden_field_tag 'event[notifications][]', nil
```